# How do I approach showing and hiding specific data fields from view when using database-modeling approach?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, data-modeling

In my use case I have a `Pump` product with several fields, like `model`, `min_flow`, `max_flow`, `active`, etc.

I want to have ability to display those fields to the user and give them the ability to edit values of those fields.  In addition to this, I want administrator users to have ability to show or hide those fields for users.

My question is about how to model my database to allow for showing and hiding of fields.  Namely, I need a way to encode fields I want to show, and those I want to hide.  I also want to let users define their own names for the fields.

Currently I have this:

```
CREATE TABLE `pump` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `model` CHAR(11),
  `min_flow` float,
  `max_flow` float,
  `active` tinyint(1),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

One way I can think of encoding names and show/hide flag is like so using MySQL's `COMMENT` metadata field, where the COMMENT field contains the name and the show/hide flag separated by a `|` separator:

```
CREATE TABLE `pump` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `model` CHAR(11) COMMENT 'Model|1',
  `min_flow` float COMMENT 'Min Flow|1',
  `max_flow` float COMMENT 'Max Flow|1',
  `active` tinyint(1) COMMENT 'Active|0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

I can then read the metadata and show/hide fields accordingly and also display the field name in the process.

Is that an acceptable way to do this, or is there a better way?

Comment: Comments are not meant to be used in this way. Why not another table with fields `tablename, fieldname, display_name, hidden` ? That's kind of what some CMS do.

Comment: Why dont simply define these rules in your application code. Maybe have some sort of a config file, which stores these constant values for every field. Or, you could have a rules class defining these conditions.